# I have lags when I'm deleting files from desktop with Xubuntu

Tags: 14.04, xubuntu, filesystem, icons

I have Xubuntu 14.04 and I am experiencing some lags when I work with desktop icons, especially when I'm deleting them.
Haven't notice that with Thunar filemanager and in System Monitor couldn't notice any other acitvity besides gnome-system-monitor.
Please help me to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this post on launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xfdesktop4/+bug/1294209/comments/32), this is a bug in [gvfs](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gvfs) and it was fixed in gvfs version >=1.23.1. Gvfs supported in Trusty Tahr 14.04 LTS is just 1.20.3 so still bugged, newer (non-LTS) releases of Ubuntu already have fixed version of gvfs included.

I am not sure if you can safely update just gvfs in 14.04.

Comment: Basically, non-LTS releases are fixed, whilst LTS hangs....?

Comment: @Alex It seems so, I have 14.04 LTS and despite the fact I update the system on regular basis gvfs in my xubuntu is still 1.20.3 and no new version for my Trusty Tahr appears to be available. I am guessing that non-LTS releases do not have this problem based on the list of gvfs packages available [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gvfs). Perhaps you can compile newer version manually for your system but I opted to wait for an official update, I do not want to brake it even more.